# Eigen matrix manipulation acceleration with OpenMP

Tags: c++, openmp, eigen

I am new to OpenMP, trying to accelerate the following for loop, but I cannot get the parallel version faster than the sequential computation.

The code snippet is as below:

```
typedef Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3 ,1> EigenVector3;
typedef Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, 1> VectorX;
std::vector<Constraint*> m_constraints;
#define block_vector(a) block<3,1>(3*(a), 0)

class Constraint{
protected:
    unsigned int m_p1, m_p2;
    double m_rest_length;
public:
    EigenVector3 EvaluateDVector(int index,  const VectorX& x){
        EigenVector3 x_ij = x.block_vector(m_p1) - x.block_vector(m_p2);
        EigenVector3 di = x_ij.normalized() * m_rest_length;
        return di;
    }
}

void evaluateDVector(  const VectorX& x, VectorX& d)
{
    d.resize(m_constraints.size()*3);
    d.setZero();
   
#pragma omp parallel for
    for (auto index = 0; index < m_constraints.size(); ++index)
    { 
        d.block_vector(index) = m_constraints[index]->EvaluateDVector(index, x);
    }
}
```

I think the reason is that the code is not paralleled, which only adds the overheads. But I don't know what might cause it.

I tried to specify x as private(x), but the openmp doesnot allow private for reference type, so I remove the const ref and pass by value, it gets even slower.

Also, I saw some posts mention that the overheads might outrun the improvement, I have 13136 constraints, and x is *7161x1* vector. This means the for-loop should loop 13k times. The parallelization should have quite a lot of impact on it.

Thank you for the help.

**Further experiment:**

I put the for-loop in the main function, where x and d ***are both member variables***(no more calling on evaluateDVector(), so no more function jump).

```
d.resize(m_constraints.size() * 3);
d.setZero();
        
#pragma omp parallel for
for (auto index = 0; index < m_constraints.size(); ++index)
{

    EigenVector3 x_ij = x.block_vector(m_constraints[index]->Getp1()) - x.block_vector(m_constraints[index]->Getp2());
    EigenVector3 di = x_ij.normalized() * m_constraints[index]->GetRestLength();
    d.block_vector(index) = di;
}
```

This parallelization speed up the computation the most. So, in my original question, I suspect I did not handle the pass-by-reference efficiently.

Comment: How many elements are in `m_constraints`?

Comment: @chrysante currently I have 13136 elements

Comment: How many cores do you have and how do you set the number of threads?

Comment: @VictorEijkhout I have 6 cores, I didnt change the threads, so by default, it should be all 12 threads.

Comment: 1. Don't use hyperthtreads. 2. You dont' know what the default is so set it explicitly through the `OMP_NUM_THREADS` variable. 3. Do a scaling study: maybe the optimal thread count is less than the number of cores.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout Thank you, I just tried it. just like you said, threads of 5 lead to the best performance. But my CPU usage is 30%(from visual studio profiling). is there is a way to exploit some of the extra power out of it?

Comment: You're parallellizing a bandwidth-bound operation. The CPU can not run faster because the data can not get to it fast enough.

Comment: What is this `block_vector` method? You seem to invoke it on Eigen vectors but I'm pretty sure it's not regular method

Comment: @Homer512 the block_vector is self-defined from block operation, sorry I forget to put in the question. It is defined as  `#define block_vector(a) block<3,1>(3*(a), 0)`

Comment: Just in case, did you enable OpenMP in your code? If not, the ```#pragma omp``` will be ignored. See how to enable OpenMP in VisualStudio
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/openmp-enable-openmp-2-0-support?view=msvc-170

Comment: I did, I switch OpenMP support to yes. Also, I have other parts of the code being paralleled, which speed up 2x, so I am sure it is working.